# How to prioritize subtitles in LAV Splitter?

Tags: subtitles

I'd like to default subtitles to **English [Forced]** (refer to Image 1) in MPC-HC, using LAV Splitter (refer to Image 2).

Also, if it'd be possible, I'd like to set the default Audio Track to Japanese [jpn].

Thanks in advance.

*Image 1: Subtitles:*

[image: subtitles]

*Image 2: LAV Splitter Settings:*

[image: LAV Splitter Settings]

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to ensure the subtitles prioritise forced, then to choose non-forced English as a backup using this:

[image: LAV Splitter - Forced as priority]

`*|f,eng*`

However, this does not guarantee it will always choose forced English (assuming this is your preferred language). So to ensure that you will always get English, I have found this seemingly works consistently

[image: LAV Splitter - Forced English as priority]

`eng|f,eng*,*|f`

This checks for forced subtitles in English, if not found, it checks for non-forced English subtitles, if neither are found, it chooses the forced subtitles.

As for setting the default audio track to Japanese, I found adjusting the order to preference did the trick.

[image: LAV Splitter - Japanese Audio Track as priority]

**NOTE:** This is not guaranteed to work for every file, there are many variations to the way subtitles are setup. I have just found this way to be the most consistent.

If you want to learn what these symbols mean I suggest studying Regular Expressions or Formal Languages, or straight up do an online course on Theory of Computing.